# JOOQ: Enum inserted at varchar even after forcing the type

Tags: kotlin, jooq

I have an **enum** in Postgres 12 as

```sql
CREATE TYPE some_type AS ENUM ('YES', 'NO', 'MAYBE');
```

I created a **user enum class** (Kotlin)

```kotlin
enum class SomeType {
    YES, NO, MAYBE;
}
```

and **forced the type** as at Gradle (kotlin script)

```kotlin
                        forcedTypes = listOf(
                            ForcedType().apply {
                                setUserType("com.example.SomeType")
                                setEnumConverter(true)
                                setIncludeExpression("column_a")
                            },
                        )
```

I want to **batch insert** data for table with a column of type - `some_type`. Following is the way I do it.

```sql
 val query = insertInto(TABLE_NAME)
                        .columns(
                            COLUMN_A, // some_type
                        )
                        .values(MAYBE, LocalDateTime.now())
                        .onDuplicateKeyUpdate()
                        .set(COLUMN_A, YES)

                },

query.bind(YES).executeAsync()
```

The code generated is typesafe with `COLUMN_A` of type `Field<SomeType>` and not `Field<ANY>`, however insert fails at runtime with following error

```
ERROR: column "column_a" is of type some_type but expression is of type character varying
  Hint: You will need to rewrite or cast the expression.
```

I see with the debugger at the `org.jooq.impl.BatchSingle` on function

```java
public final BatchSingle bind(Object... bindValues) {
        allBindValues.add(bindValues);
        return this;
    }
```

That the prepared query is sending `varchar`

```sql
insert into "public"."sometable" (
  "column_a",
  "record_timestamp"
)
values (
  'MAYBE'
)
```

Am I missing some config somewhere?

Comment: answer for this question can help you [insert-an-enum-value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52814083/insert-an-enum-value-into-an-unknown-table-with-jooq)

Comment: Had same error with `EnumType` implementation. I think its a problem with batch Insert.

Comment: i think you can try to tell more explicit to postgres and set the value with casting something like this: `value::some_type`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 bind values in your query:

- `LocalDateTime.now()`
- `YES`

However, when batching, you're binding only 1. Just pass both of them to the batch:

```java
query.bind(LocalDateTime.now(), YES).executeAsync()
```

Comment: I can't believe it was so simple. Yes, I can see in the debugger too in the question. However I woner why the error message is regarding enum being varchar. 

Maybe I made a type when creating this question on stackoverflow. Real query was way bigger.

Comment: @MangatRaiModi: All bind values shift by 1 (or so), so there might as well have been a String value being bound at the position of the enum...

Comment: Hmm that makes sense. Maybe it would have been better for the jooq to detect bind mismatch. I wonder if it can't be done.

Thanks a lot @LukasEder